# Increase security in SQL Server with known login that cannot be changed or dropped?

Tags: sql-server, security, spoofing

I have a server type software connected to my local SQL Server and it has a hardcoded SQL login/password(also requires sqladmin role) inside that I CAN NOT change. As I have to use this software, I had to create this login in my SQL Server. Now the issue is, this hardcoded login info is well known on the internet, ask google with few keywords and clicks you can find it. Also I CAN NOT close 1433 or any SQL Server port on firewall as my clients need to access to my SQL Server for data and functions.

So to prevent people who know this infomation and want to use it against / break into my SQL Server. I did below security measures:

1. Turned off SQL Server's remote connection function
2. Create an logon trigger to allow only local communication for this login

Now the question is, can someone spoof as localhost to send me an packet with SQL command such as DROP TRIGGER etc. to break in?

If so what other counter measures I can use? Heaps thanks!

Trigger as below

```
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_ip 
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @LoginName sysname
DECLARE @LoginType sysname
  
SET @LoginName = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
 
IF(@LoginName = 'HardcodedLogin' AND (EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]','nvarchar(128)') IN ('<local machine>')))
BEGIN
RETURN; -- Login Authorized
END

ELSE IF(@LoginName IN ('SecuredLoginForClients'))
BEGIN
RETURN; -- Login Authorized
END

ELSE            
BEGIN
ROLLBACK; -- Disconnect the session
END

END
```

[image: Screenshot for SSMS remote connection]

Comment: this means any disgruntled employee can login to your server locally and change trigger. i think it's easier to just hack the password inside the software using a hex editor or something

Comment: also, i don't get it, you write: `Turned off SQL Server's remote connection function`but then you write `Also I CAN NOT close 1433 or any SQL Server port on firewall `

Comment: @siggemannen the SQL Server's remote connection function is for SSMS remote connection, so I turned it off already to prevent hackers from using SSMS to remote login into my SQL Server. Then for 1433, I have to open it for clients to use SecuredClientLogin to send and receive data to and from my SQL Server right? I can't close it or the client software can not function.

Comment: Are the clients on the inside of your network?

Comment: @siggemannen Also those clients won't do that, there is no need to worry about them, those clients aren't humans, they are client software BTW.

Comment: @siggemannen no, clients are not in my local network.

Comment: So you couldn't have turned off remote connection? because then they wouldn't be able to connect. Are you talking about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16 perhaps? it doesn't really affect what you need

Comment: ClientHost is a TDS property, ie. you pass it in login package, so i'm pretty sure it can be spoofed to be anything one wants

Comment: @siggemannen No.. what I mean is I turned off the remote connection in my SSMS server settings, so no remote login from other SSMS. However, the 1433 port needs to be opened for client software to communicate with the SQL Server. My concern is, can a hacker use this known hardcoded login with spoofing as localhost to connect to my SQL Server?

Comment: you should probably at least whitelist the iPs of clients connecting from outside and then close the rest. `I turned off the remote connection in my SSMS server settings` - can you put a screenshot on which setting you're talking about? SSMS isn't the only way to connect you know

Comment: "also requires sqladmin role" - security breach waiting to happen .... Fix the real problem!!!

Comment: Ok, yeah, that setting only affect linked servers, it has nothing to do with remote access from regular clients. So it doesn't really matter if it's on or off for your case

Comment: @siggemannen SS attached, I can't whitelist those client software's IPs as those clients are designed to be used anywhere, I would no way know all the IPs. The SecuredClientLogin is hardcoded in the client software so users don't know, they just use my client software for functions.

Comment: @MitchWheat You inspired me! I can map it to read and write only to its own certain databases, so even if a hack finds a way to use it against me, all he/she can do is destroy that database's data, which is being backed up every day.

Comment: For this reason usually one creates an api which fetches data through standardised way instead of giving access to raw sql server connections